# Trying to set up a Node.Js Server which calls a Python Script

Tags: python, node.js

I am Trying to set up a simple Node.Js Server which calls a Python Script on hitting a url. Given below are the python and Node js server file.

When I hit the server url. The page loads! but then the server crashes and It give me the following error (in the cmd prompt):

```
    Server listening on: http://localhost:8080/
this is here so we are in
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn C:UsersShubhamAnaconda3libos.py ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:429:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:343:17)
```

and this in the Web browser console:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I have checked similar issues. But they are a little different and their fixes don't help me. 
I HAVE CLEARED THE CACHE AND CHECKED.

Python file:

```
import sys
def runForFun(artist, song, lyrics):
    if lyrics is None:
        print("artist:" + artist)
        print("song:"+song)
        print("lyrics:"+lyrics)

        theme = "theme"
        return theme
    else :
        print("lyrics: "+lyrics)


try:    
    runForFun(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
except IndexError:
    print('Please supply arguments')
```

Node js file

```
//Lets require/import the HTTP module
var http = require('http');
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

//Lets define a port we want to listen to
const PORT=8080; 

//We need a function which handles requests and send response
function handleRequest(request, response){


    var options = {
      mode: 'text',
      pythonPath: 'C:\Users\Shubham\Anaconda3\lib\os.py',
      pythonOptions: ['-u'],
      scriptPath: 'C:\Users\Shubham\Google Drive\Capstone\Theme Extraction',
      args: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
    };

    console.log("this is here so we are in");

    PythonShell.run('runPython.py', options, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('results: %j', results, 'finished');
});
    response.end('It Works!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);
}

//Create a server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

//Lets start our server
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s/", PORT);
});
```

Comment: Just read that error.. `Error: spawn C:UsersShubhamAnaconda3libos.py` Does that look like a file path? You likely need to escape the backslashes

Comment: Also, I think `pythonPath` needs to point at the python executable file, not a python script.

Comment: How is `var options` in your code something that is internal? You need `C:\\Users`, for example

Comment: No not the var options, I was replying to your 1st comment. 

Working on your second suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: My comments are related. You error is referring to the `var options` where you have unescaped backslashes at `pythonPath: 'C:\Users\Shubham\Anaconda3\lib\os.py'`

Comment: Yes! thanks. Very silly mistake. I copy pasted the path from the window address bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape the slashes in the file paths and I think the `pythonPath` should point at a Python executable file, not a script.

Therefore, the correct setup would look like this

```
var options = {
      mode: 'text',
      pythonPath: 'C:\\Python\\pythonw.exe',
      pythonOptions: ['-u'],
      scriptPath: 'C:\\Users\\Shubham\\Google Drive\\Capstone\\Theme Extraction',
      args: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
    };
```

Though, overall, unless you specifically need Node.js, why not use a Python web framework that you could simply import your script to run it?

Comment: I was just trying to learn. I will try python web framework as well. Thanks!